# Python Flask templates use {{}} can't mix javascript var

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask, jinja2

Here is my problem. PictureLenth is my picture array length, and ProductImage is a list. I can't use now to point my array address on ProductImage. How can I use javascript var on {{}}?

```
lenth = {{ PictureLenth }}-1;
now = 0;

function t_setInterval() {
window.intervalParam = window.setInterval(function() {
var date = new Date();
   if (lenth>now)
   {now = now + 1;}
   else
   {now = 0;}
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src="data:image/png;base64, {{ ProductImage[now] }}";
    return false;
}, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Jinja doesn't have any access to `now` when it runs on the server side and when the JavaScript runs on the client side the string is static and will never change.  The solution is to provide `ProductImage` as a JavaScript variable using [Flask's `tojson` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters):

```
var images = {{ ProductImage | tojson | safe }},
    length = images.length - 1,
    now = 0;

function t_setInterval() {
  window.intervalParam = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (length > now) now = now + 1;
    else now = 0;
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64, " + images[now];
    return false;
  }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lenth = {{ PictureLenth }}-1;
now = 0;

function t_setInterval() {
window.intervalParam = window.setInterval(function() {
var date = new Date();
   if (lenth>now)
   {now = now + 1;}
   else
   {now = 0;}
    var ProductImage = {{ProductImage|safe}};
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src="data:image/png;base64,"+ProductImage[now];
    return false;
}, 4000);
}
```